# Attaching wood to glass?

Tags: adhesives, glass, wood

I want to make a floor/plateau in a glass terrarium.

A dwarf hamster will use it, so they're not very heavy, but I'd like to be able to place some things like a small food dish, maybe some decoration etc on the plateau.

My initial idea was to use aquarium sealant to secure the plateau. I would then use a max of 1-2 pillars per plateau. I would prefer to have 3 plateaus at 3 different levels, connected with stairs/bridges. **Will a minimal amount of pillars and the aquarium sealant be enough to hold it up securely?**

**Can sealant like silicone/aquarium be removed without leaving too many traces on the glass?** A few scratches I can deal with.

The layout will be somewhat like this:

[image]

Excuse my great drawing skills, I hope this explains what I need.

Comment: A word of warning... Hamsters love to gnaw on wood, so don't expect your structures to last forever and be very careful not to use poisonous or pressure-treated wood.

Comment: @HenryTaylor thanks! Luckily my current hamster is not interested in chewing on wood, he's left all his wood structures alone so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to consider:

1. Wood may soak up water and then swell, and glass terrariums/aquariums are not infinitely sturdy, so try not to have a straight piece of wood reaching from one pane to the opposite pane (your layout looks fine itr).
2. I you have an L-shaped glueing area (i.e. a platform plus a ramp, fitted together as one unit (the L being along-and-up) or a platform in a corner (the L being along-both-panes)) any silicone should be able to carry your platform and your hamster. So you could have the two edge platforms and then an assembly of the middle platform well-attached to the two ramps. No pillars needed.

Silicone can be removed from flat and non-iced glass perfectly with a razorblade.